# Obscure sci-fi illustration book showing speculative alien life forms on other worlds

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space, illustrated-story

This book has to have been published in the early '90s or before.

It was an illustration book showing speculative alien life forms on other worlds. I checked it out from the library at school every week. The only illustration I remember is a cat-like alien with red skin and scales and sharp fangs and possibly a forked tongue.

Anyone have any idea at all? I can’t remember.

Comment: I don't have a copy to hand right now, but this sounds a lot like [*Barlow's Guide to Extraterrestrials*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1818).

Comment: @DavidW: I also immediately thought about *Barlowe's Guide*, but I just leafed through it, and there was no "cat-like alien with red skin and scales and sharp fangs".

Comment: Was it a big book - i.e. very tall? Were the aliens presented as though they were on wanted posters?

Comment: Cat like alien with red skin - that sounds a bit like a Kzint from Larry Niven's books..

Comment: There's another Barlowe book, called Expedition to Darwin-something (or maybe just Expedition?) which may have this alien creature?

Comment: You don't happen to have six thumbs on your both hands, do you?

Comment: Also asked on Reddit: https://old.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/16v1t4v/need_help_locating_a_obscure_space_book/

Answer (score 23):

I believe this is the 1979 *Galactic Encounters* series artbook [*Aliens in Space: An Illustrated Guide to the Inhabited Galaxy*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1771246) by Stewart Cowley (writing as Stephen Caldwell).

The cover art actually seems pretty close to what you describe:

[image: cover of "Aliens in Space", showing a red cat-like alien]

This picture appears again in the section for the planet "Hades" which also has this red-skinned reptilian alien with a forked tongue:

[image: A man in a red jumpsuit points a handgun at a reptilian alien with a spiky crest, pointy fangs and a forked tongue. The alien has a prehensile tail which is wrapping around the man's arm.]

Comment: One of the illustrations inside is clearly Cthulhu.

Comment: This author is a pseudonym for Stewart Cowley who wrote (but did not illustrate IIRC) the fantastic Terran Trade Authority books ( https://archive.org/details/terrantradeauthorityhandbookstarliners/page/n89/mode/2up )

Answer (score 10):

I think this may have been the wonderful *[Barlowe's Guide to Extraterrestrials](https://archive.org/details/barlowesguidetoe00barl)*.  It does not contain an alien exactly like what you describe, although it contains two different quadrupeds which, taken together, fit reasonably well:  the Demon (from *A Plague of Demons* by Keith Laumer) and the Ishtarian (from *Fire Time* by Poul Anderson).

[image: Demon]

[image: Ishtarian]

For the red color, you may be remembering either the pinkish of the Demon or the leaves around the neck of the Ishtarian.  Those red shapes are actually part of the growing plant that the alien carries with it, but they could easily be mistaken or misremembered as scales.  Neither has a forked tongue, but the Demon has quite threatening needle-like teeth.

Comment: Gotta put the cover with the cool guy with twenty fingers and four thumbs, or that page if you can find it. https://www.amazon.com/Barlowes-Guide-Extraterrestrials-Douglas-Barlowe/dp/0894801120